# Simple console based car array

Tags: java, object-oriented, homework

I have recently started coding in Java and I had to do this assignment in college.

> Develop a menu driven application called `TestCarPartc` that allows the user to add, remove and list Car objects.  For this use an `ArrayList` of `Car`.  What are the advantages of using an `ArrayList` over an array? Place the answer in a comment at the end of your code.

I am trying to wrap my head around the concept of OOP and I am not quite sure when should I make something a new class or if I should implement something as interface or make some classes inherit from the other.

How does it look like in a real programming job? Would my code be considered "well written" for its purposes? What are the things I should look out for?

Console Menu:

```
package CarPartsB;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarPartsMenu {

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
private CarsArray carsList = new CarsArray();
private boolean loopVariable = true;

public void showMenu() {

    while (loopVariable) {
        try {
            System.out.println("1: Add car.\n2: Remove car.\n3: List cars.\n4: Exiting");
            int userInput = console.nextInt();
            switch (userInput) {
                case 1:
                    addCar();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    removeCar();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    listCars();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    loopVariable = false;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            console.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\n" + e + " \nhas happened, choose value from 1 o 4.\n Click enter to continue...");
            console.nextLine();
        }
    }
}

private void addCar() {
    String make, model;
    int year;
    double price;
    try {
        System.out.println("What's price of your car? ");
        price = console.nextDouble();
        validateInput(price);
        System.out.println("What year was your car made?");
        year = console.nextInt();
        validateInputYear(year);
        System.out.println("What's the make of your car?");
        make = console.next();
        System.out.println("What's the model of your car?");
        model = console.next();
        Car car = new Car(price, year, make, model);
        carsList.addCar(car);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n" + e + "\nhas happened, make sure to input correct values.\n Click enter to continue...");
        console.nextLine();
    }
}

private void removeCar() {
    if (carsList.isEmpty()) {
        console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("There are no cars in the list");
        console.nextLine();
    } else {
        try {
            System.out.println("Type id of the car you want to remove: ");
            int userInputID = console.nextInt();
            carsList.removeCar(userInputID);
            System.out.println("Car with ID: " + userInputID + " has been removed.\n");
            console.nextLine();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            console.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\n" + e + "\nhas happened, you have to pick ID that EXISTS.\n Click enter to continue...");
            console.nextLine();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            console.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\n" + e + "\nhas happened, input an integer.\n Click enter to continue...");
            console.nextLine();
        }
    }
}

private void listCars() {
    console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("List of cars: ");
    carsList.printCars();
    System.out.println("\nPress anything to continue...");
    console.nextLine();
}

private void validateInputYear(int number) {
    if (number < 1900 || number > 2018) {
        throw new InputMismatchException("\nYou can't add car that was made earlier than 1900\n or after 2018");
    }
}

private void validateInput(double number) {
    if (number <= 0) {
        throw new InputMismatchException("\nPrice can't be negative or zero.");
    }
}

}
```

`Array` Class:

```
package CarPartsB;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CarsArray {

    private ArrayList<Car> carsArray;

    public CarsArray() {
        this.carsArray = new ArrayList();
    }

    public ArrayList<Car> getCars() {
        return this.carsArray;
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.carsArray.size();
    }

    public void addCar(Car element) {
        this.carsArray.add(element);
    }

    public void removeCar(int carId) {
        Car carToRemove = null;
        for (Car c : carsArray) {
            if (c.getCarID() == carId) {
                carToRemove = c;
            }
        }
        if (carToRemove != null) {
            carsArray.remove(carToRemove);
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    public void printCars() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty..");
        } else {
            for (Car c : carsArray) {
                c.printDetails();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return carsArray.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

`Car` Class:

```
package CarPartsB;

public class Car {

    private double price;
    private int year_of_production;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int yearsOld;
    private int carID;
    static int CAR_ID;

    public Car(double price, int year_of_production, String make, String model) {
        this.price = price;
        this.year_of_production = year_of_production;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.yearsOld = 2018 - this.year_of_production;
        this.carID = CAR_ID;
        CAR_ID++;

    }

    public int getCarID() {
        return this.carID;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setYear_of_production(int year_of_production) {
        this.year_of_production = year_of_production;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getYear_of_production() {
        return year_of_production;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println("ID:" + this.carID + " " + this.make + " "
                + this.model + " is " + this.yearsOld + " "
                + "years old and has price of " + this.price);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not change the code in the question after receiving an answer. Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for alternatives.  I have rolled-back the edit for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `Car`

Your `Car` class has what I would consider deficiencies.

The `make`, `model`, `year_of_production` and `carId` shouldn’t change after creating a car.  They should be `final`.   Attributes like the `price` (and colour and condition) of the car can change.

Inconsistent usage of `this.`. The function `getCarID()` doesn’t need it.

**Bug**: The method `setYear_of_production` doesn’t change the `yearsOld` member!!!

The constructor uses a hard-coded `2018`.

The `yearsOld` member should not be a member at all, but a getter method which relies on the year of production and the current year.  If after putting cars on the list, a year goes by, the cars current don’t (and can’t) age!  If you haven’t learnt how to query the current year, at least use a parameter or a global static (volatile, not constant) value.

Your `Car` class is a data model class.  It shouldn’t have “output” functions.  The class could be used by a console application or a GUI application.  “Debug” output is fine, but don’t print output if you can avoid it.  And you can.  Write a `Car.toString()` function, and the caller could `System.out.println(car)`.  Or better, add a `printCarDetails()` in `CarPartsMenu`.   For the same reasons, I’d move `printCars()` out of `CarsArray` (a data model class) into `CarPartsMenu`.

---

### `CarsArray`

The `carsArray` should be final.

`.getCars()`, `.size()`, and `.addCar()` all unnecessarily use `this.`.

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is not the right exception to use.  [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) is a better semantic match.

---

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have modified code in my question to reflect changes that you mentioned. Are there any other things you would suggest on improving?

Comment: I have rolled-back your edit to the original question.  See the "I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?" section of [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for information on how to create followup questions when you want additional feedback after incorporating changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code to the suggestions, what are other things that could be worked on? Thank you for your help.

Car Menu:

```
package CarPartsB;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarPartsMenu {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final CarsArray carsList = new CarsArray();
    private boolean loopVariable = true;

    public void showMenu() {

        while (loopVariable) {
            try {
                System.out.println("1: Add car.\n2: Remove car.\n3: List cars.\n4: Exiting");
                int userInput = console.nextInt();
                switch (userInput) {
                    case 1:
                        addCar();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        removeCar();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        listCars();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        loopVariable = false;
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                console.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\n" + e + " \nhas happened, choose value from 1 o 4.\n Click enter to continue...");
                console.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }

    private void addCar() {
        String make, model;
        int year;
        double price;
        try {
            System.out.println("What's price of your car? ");
            price = console.nextDouble();
            validateInput(price);
            System.out.println("What year was your car made?");
            year = console.nextInt();
            validateInputYear(year);
            System.out.println("What's the make of your car?");
            make = console.next();
            System.out.println("What's the model of your car?");
            model = console.next();
            Car car = new Car(price, year, make, model);
            carsList.addCar(car);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            console.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\n" + e + "\nhas happened, make sure to input correct values.\n Click enter to continue...");
            console.nextLine();
        }
    }

    private void removeCar() {
        if (carsList.isEmpty()) {
            console.nextLine();
            System.out.println("There are no cars in the list");
            console.nextLine();
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("Type id of the car you want to remove: ");
                int userInputID = console.nextInt();
                carsList.removeCar(userInputID);
                System.out.println("Car with ID: " + userInputID + " has been removed.\n");
                console.nextLine();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                console.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\n" + e + "\nhas happened, you have to pick ID that EXISTS.\n Click enter to continue...");
                console.nextLine();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                console.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\n" + e + "\nhas happened, input an integer.\n Click enter to continue...");
                console.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }

    private void listCars() {
        console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("List of cars: ");
        printCarDetails();
        System.out.println("\nPress anything to continue...");
        console.nextLine();
    }

    private void printCarDetails() {
         if (carsList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty..");
        }else {
            for(Car c : carsList.getCars()) {
                System.out.println("ID:" + c.getCarID() + " " + c.getMake() + " "
                + c.getModel() + " is " + c.getYearsOld() + " "
                + "years old and has price of " + c.getPrice());
            }
         }

    }

    private void validateInputYear(int number) {
        if (number < 1900 || number > 2018) {
            throw new InputMismatchException("\nYou can't add car that was made earlier than 1900\n or after 2018");
        }
    }

    private void validateInput(double number) {
        if (number <= 0) {
            throw new InputMismatchException("\nPrice can't be negative or zero.");
        }
    }

}
```

`Array` Class

```
package CarPartsB;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class CarsArray extends ArrayList {

    private final ArrayList<Car> carsArray;

    public CarsArray() {
        this.carsArray = new ArrayList();
    }

    public ArrayList<Car> getCars() {
        return carsArray;
    }

    public int size() {
        return carsArray.size();
    }

    public void addCar(Car element) {
        carsArray.add(element);
    }

    public void removeCar(int carId) {
        Car carToRemove = null;
        for (Car c : carsArray) {
            if (c.getCarID() == carId) {
                carToRemove = c;
            }
        }
        if (carToRemove != null) {
            carsArray.remove(carToRemove);
        } else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return carsArray.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

`Car` Class

```
package CarPartsB;

import java.time.Year;

public class Car {

    private double price;
    private final int year_of_production;
    private final String make;
    private final String model;
    private final int yearsOld;
    private final int carID;
    static int CAR_ID;
    int year = Year.now().getValue();


    public Car(double price, int year_of_production, String make, String model) {
        this.price = price;
        this.year_of_production = year_of_production;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.yearsOld = year - this.year_of_production;
        this.carID = CAR_ID;
        CAR_ID++;

    }

    public int getYearsOld() {
        return yearsOld;
    }

    public int getCarID() {
        return carID;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getYear_of_production() {
        return year_of_production;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

}
```